# MVC 4 Multi-Select List Box and Checked List Box

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, multi-select, html.listboxfor

I want to do a similar implementation done by Sivaraman Dhamodharan in MVC 4 asp.net in his article found on: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/139792/Multi-Select-List-Box-and-Checked-List-Box

I am new in MVC 4 and I'm enjoying it!

Comment: And what's your question? Please explain, what problem do you have.

Answer (score -1):

You can create Multi-Select boxes for "Visit Area" and "Assigned Id" (as mentioned in the article you have put) very easily in MVC. For the select box with the checkboxes, you can create a table in MVC.

Please follow the steps below.

Let's assume that that the view model for the page is AssignWorkViewModel and the view model for the product is ProductViewModel.

```
public class AssignWorkViewModel
{

    public List<ProductViewModel> Products { get; set; }
}


public class ProductViewModel
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    //used to bind the checkbox value in the view
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Let's assume that the action method name is "AssignWork"

```
public ActionResult AssignWork()
    {
        AssignWorkViewModel model = new AssignWorkViewModel();

        List<ProductViewModel> products = new List<ProductViewModel>();

        //let's add some values
        ProductViewModel samsungMonitor = new ProductViewModel();
        samsungMonitor.ProductId = 1;
        samsungMonitor.IsSelected = false;
        samsungMonitor.ProductName = "Samsung Monitor";
        products.Add(samsungMonitor);

        ProductViewModel sonyDvd = new ProductViewModel();
        sonyDvd.ProductId = 2;
        sonyDvd.IsSelected = false;
        sonyDvd.ProductName = "Sony DVD";
        products.Add(sonyDvd);

        ProductViewModel motherBoard = new ProductViewModel();
        motherBoard.ProductId = 3;
        motherBoard.IsSelected = false;
        motherBoard.ProductName = "Pentium Mother Board";
        products.Add(motherBoard);

        model.Products = products;

        //pass model to the view
        return View(model);
    }
```

The View,

```
@model SelectBoxTest.ViewModels.AssignWorkViewModel
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Products)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.HiddenFor(model => item.ProductId)</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => item.IsSelected)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ProductName)</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

The result,

[image]

I think this might help you to start.